# What will be appropriate in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What did the king do when he become/became angry? 
I am not a native speaker so am confused that since did is used in the begining, what will be correct, become or became? 
Also, what rule governs it?

Comment: You might find our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), to be a better fit for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are confused is that you are not noticing that "did" is the helper for "do" in this sentence. It is not the helping verb for "became" (and that's the correct form -- it's the simple past tense).